# How to remove keys for list of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have list of objects created like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < retrievedContactsArr.length; i++){
    for(var k = 0; k < result.length; k++){
        if(retrievedContactsArr[i].contact.phone.cell && retrievedContactsArr[i].contact.phone.cell === result[k].contact.phone.cell){
            retrievedContactsArr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    retrievedContactsObj[i] = retrievedContactsArr[i];
}
```

But they are created with keys `"0", "1"` like this:

```
{
    "0": {
        "contact": {
            "address": {
                "home": "",
                "office": ""
            },
        },
        "name": "Test3"
    },
    "1": {
        "contact": {
            "address": {
                "home": "",
                "office": ""
            },
        },
        "name": "Test2"
    }
}
```

How do I remove the keys for the above object ?

Comment: Use an array maybe? Not sure what you are looking to accomplish here.

Comment: Because object are the same, how can you distinguish that from each other? You shuold use an array to do that